# Deleting observations from a data frame, according to a bernoulli random variable that is 0 or 1

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I have a data frame with 1000 rows. I want to delete 500 observations from a specific column `Y`, in a way thet the bigger the values of `Y`, the probability it will be deleted is bigger.
One way to do that is to sort this column in an ascending way. For `i = 1,...,1000`, toss a bernoulli random variable with a `p_i` probability for success that is dependant on `i`. delete all observations that their bernoulli random variable is 1.

So first I sort this column:

`df_sorted = df.sort_values("mycolumn")`

Next, I tried something like this:

```
p_i = np.linspace(0,1,num=sample_Encoded_sorted.shape[0])
bernoulli = np.random.binomial(1, p_i)
delete_index = bernoulli == 1
```

I get `delete_index` is a boolian vector with `True` or `False`, and the probability to get a True is higher among higher index. However, I get more than 500 `True` in it.

How do I get only 500 Trues in this vector? and how do I use it to delete the corresponding rows of the data frame?

For example if i = 1 in `delete_index` is `False`, the first row of the data frame wont be deleted, if it's `True` it will be deleted.

Comment: You can try using your normalized values as probabilities, as long as you want to remove high values with a higher probability.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why are you trying to limit the appearance of True and False to 500, due to the random binomial it will be near from 500 but most of the time it wont be 500, but here it is one possible solution, i don't know how useful it is for your purposes.

```
p_i = np.linspace(0,1,num=1000)

#We make a loop that make the number 1 appear 500 times
count=0
while count != 500:
  bernoulli = np.random.binomial(1, p_i)
  count=np.sum(bernoulli)

#We transform the array that we got from np.random.binomial into a boolean mask and slice the sorted_df
df_sorted=df_sorted[pd.Series(bernoulli)==0]
#This will return a new DataFrame with the 500 values
```

I hope this helps, i can't comment yet because of my reputation, thats why I put this as an answer and not a comment.

Comment: Thank you! can you please also do it that not the whole observations would be deleted? on the their values of the Y column ?

Comment: Do you mean create a copy of the DataFrame instead of replace it?